# How to pass a token to another dashboard in Splunk in table dropdown when that token is not in any table column?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

In my Splunk table, I have three columns as Id, Name and Place.
The table values are coming from my search which has a token from a dropdown above it.
A simplified version of the query looks as below :

```
index=main target=$myTarget$ | table Id, Name, Place
```

My requirement is to create a table drilldown on this and pass $myTarget$ to the linking dashboard. But since I am not showing target in my table I am not able to pass it as $row.$ or any other (like $click.value2$ etc.)

Is it possible to pass a token which is not in the table fields to another dashboard by drilldown ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing `$myTarget$` or `$form.myTarget$`?

Comment: @RichG Yes, but it does not come in the drilldown  drop down list for adding parameters hence it does not work.